# How to associate two ParseGeoPoint objects to the same user in parse.com backend?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to store two ParseGeoPoint objects: src and dest where src is the currentLocation of the user and dest is a location generated from an address using geocoding. Each user in my app must have or rather has a src and a dest. I created a ParseClass that has a ParseUser obj and two ParseGeoPoint objects namely src and dest. However when i attempt to store an instance of this class it returns a ParseException which states only 1 ParseGeoPoint object can be stored in a class. I understand that this may be a limitation of parse.

However i need them to be in the same class because : I intend to run queries to retrieve a list of users to the same dest and ordered by their src. In this way my app users can find other users in their proximity going to the same dest. The results are to be populated in a list view using the ParseQueryAdapter.

This is what i'm doing now. If it helps make the situation clearer

```
    // Set up a customized query
    ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<UserLocationObject> factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<UserLocationObject>() 
    {
        public ParseQuery<UserLocationObject> create()
        {
            Location myLoc =currentLocation;
            ParseGeoPoint src=geoPointFromLocation(myLoc);              
            ParseQuery<UserLocationObject> query = UserLocationObject.getQuery();
            query.include("user");query.whereNear("src", src);query.whereEqualTo("dest", dest);
            query.setLimit(MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS);
            return query;
          }
        };

    // Set up the query adapter
    locationInfo = new ParseQueryAdapter<UserLocationObject>(this, factory) {
      @Override
      public View getItemView(UserLocationObject post, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
          view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_find_poolers, null);
        }
        return view;
      }
    };
    // Attach the query adapter to the view
ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listView_findPoolers);
listView.setAdapter(locationInfo);
```

Is there a way in which i can store the src and dest of an user so that i can easily query them and populate my list view. The list should be generated satisfying the above mentioned contraints.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseGeoPoint.html):

> Only one key in a class may contain a GeoPoint.

One thing that comes to mind is creating two additional classes each containing a `ParseGeoPoint` and add a relation to them from your `User` class. For example, you can create the `Origin` class and the `Destination` class and make each of them have a column with a `ParseGeoPoint`. Then you add a reference to each class from the `User` class.

Comment: That is the first thing that came to my mind. But what query can i write so that my listview is populated with users who have the same destn and are near the src?
I believe i would have to query two different classes and combine the reults in some way. But how do i combine them and populate the listview?

Comment: I just discovered that it seems Parse objects can now include multiple geopoints. I get no error when saving such the objects or when querying them. Hope this is indeed a new feature and not that I've missed something.